# Border-radius without rounding

Tags: css

Im trying to get div's with one cutted out corner. Im using :

```
border-radius: 0px 50px 0px 0px;
```

Sadly, im getting corner with rounded corner, but im really need corner with flat, 45' cut. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTZfW.png) is what i need. Prefer pure CSS, but solution in JavaScript will be perfect also.

Clarification edit : 
I forgot to mention that i need reveal gradient background with this corner, and also - div with background = panel-body from bootstrap 2.3.2

```
HTML :
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="inner-div"><h2>Example</h2></div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS :
#panel-body {background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS triangles to the rescue:

```css
div.cutCorner{
    height: 200px;
    background: pink;
    position: relative;
}

div.cutCorner:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    right: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid white;
    border-left: 50px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="cutCorner"></div>
```

```css
body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/);
  background-size: cover;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 25%, 75% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 25%, 75% 0);
  background-image:linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  padding: 10px;
}

**AS per OP's edit**, this idea supports image background and gradient div :)
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance to get similar effect but with transparent corner? I want to reveal gradient from div with background. I added clarification edit in main post.

Comment: ..so rather than making it "look like" the corner has been cut off, you want to "literally" (well you know what I mean) cut it off. Right?

Comment: @user3282071 - See my update which supports gradient background div and image background page :)

Comment: @user3282071 Was this any use to you? Would appreciate the accept for the effort :)

Comment: Now works perfect. Thank you so much and sorry for my late response.

Comment: No problem, my pleasure

Answer (score 2):

> > You can try like as -

```css
.box{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
.box1{ border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px;}
.box2{ border-radius: 0px 10px 0px 0px;}
.box3{ border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 0px;}

/*-------------OR-------------*/

.box11:before,.box22:before,.box33:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.box11:before{
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   border-top: 10px solid white;
   border-right: 10px solid red;
 }
 .box22:before{
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   border-top: 10px solid white;
   border-left: 10px solid red;
 }
 .box33:before{
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   border-bottom: 10px solid white;
   border-left: 10px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
<div class="box box3"></div>

<div class="box box11"></div>
<div class="box box22"></div>
<div class="box box33"></div>
```

Comment: Any change to get similar effect but with transparent corner? I want to reveal gradient from div with background.

Comment: You can also apply gradient border style for corner borders. Here is the `CSS tricks` link https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/ @user3282071

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this effect with `border-radius`, you need to use a variety of different css properties to achieve this effect.

Here's the markup:

```
<div class="cut-corner"></div>
```

Here's the styles:

```
.cut-corner {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
}

.cut-corner:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid white;
    border-left: 50px solid #000;
    width: 0;
}
```